# Pandas Read Excel and Keep trailing zeroes for dollar signs

Tags: excel, pandas, currency, currency-formatting

pandas==0.25.3
python 3.7

I have an microsoft excel spread sheet that I want to read into pandas. Currently, when I take a cell that has a fractional currency ending in 0 (e.g. 12.50), the output in pandas is 12.5. I want this to work on any cell that this occurs in (e.g. I won't know the cell ahead of time).

In excel, the number looks like `$12.50` in the cell. When I use pandas read_excel, the output is `12.5`. It looses both the dollar sign and the trailing zero. In the format line above I see `12.5` so, maybe this is an excel issue and not a pandas issue.

I figured if it kept the dollar sign then I could cycle through the spreadsheet and take all entries that start with a dollar sign and format them to end with 2 trailing zeros.

Cell:

[image]

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')
print(df)
print(df.dtypes)
```

Pandas:

```
amount 
 500.0 
2217.5
```

Has anyone else run across this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Do you not know the units of the column? (ie: $)

Comment: `int` will always curtail the trailing zero. You can try reading columns as `string`
Try this:


```df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx'', dtype=str)```

Comment: I have the same issue. Unfortunately, specifying the data type via `df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', dtype=str)` or `df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', dtype={'amount': str})` does not prevent pandas from adding ".0" at the end of each number.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas isn't able to read Excel's number format however you might be able to use the library `openpyxl`and use the `.number_format` method to read the formats and parse your data into your desired output.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename = r'..\test.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']
a2 = ws['A2'].value
a2_num_format = ws['A2'].number_format
print(a2, a2_num_format)
```

Output:

```
500 "$"#,##0.00;[Red]\-"$"#,##0.00
```